# Superquery - Displays count results along a script

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

In Superquery IDE -> Bigquery database, I'm trying to display select count(1) results after creating a temporary table during a script execution (Begin-End format). I'm only getting the result from the last select count(1), the others are not displayed by the IDE. How can I do this? any workaround?

In the Google Cloud Platform all the results are displayed
Thanks in advance